# Bootrap/Rails - collapsible navbar doesn't work in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [responsive navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) from Bootstrap. In mobile the menu icon appears but there's no drop-down menu when I click on it. I've browsed SO because this seems to be a common problem but data-target id is correct and that seems to be the problem everyone else had. I can't spot any errors in the JS either, none are being thrown in the console when I inspected the page with Chrome's Dev-tools. Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-area">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= image_tag "logo-wide-small.png", :class => "img-responsive" %>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-links-area" id="responsive-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Signup", '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Login", '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Language", '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "JOIN NOW", '#', {:class => "btn btn-warning", :role => "button"} %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help you would be much appreciated. Also, I'm testing this with Chrome's Responsive Web Design Tester and not an actual device, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html markup looks ok so try checking if your `bootstrap.js` is included **after** the `jQuery.js` file like this:

```
<script src="/jQuery.js"></script>
<!--followed by the bootstrap script-->
<script src="/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Edit the path files according to the CDNs or folders they're in, of course

Comment: I've just checked on Devtools and it doesn't look like bootstrap.js is being loaded at all. I'm using RoR and the bootstrap-sass gem so any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, just realised I'm missing the //require statement in application.js! Gonna go fix that now.

Comment: It's working now, such a silly mistake! Thanks for the help, I totally didn't think to check that :)

Comment: Nice!! Glad I could help :) Btw, you merged your bootstrap with application.js??

Comment: I don't think it's merged exactly, but the bootstrap-sass gem needs you to require bootstrap sprockets in application.js

Comment: Not that fluent with ruby so I have no idea what sprockets mean lol

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and I put this under the <%= yeild %> and it worked

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```